# How to use "call getchar@PLT" to emulate getting each character of a string in ASSEMBLY (GCC)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

I need to replicate the following C code using Assembly Code:

```
puts("Enter a string of 0s and 1s: ");
while ( ((input = getchar()) != '\n') ) {

if ( (input != '0') && (input != '1') ) { // invalid input
puts("ERROR: invalid input");
return 1;
}
```

I'm fairly new to assembly, but I'm told to use "getchar@PLT" to replicate the loop above. How would I go about using this in a loop? The only code I have so far in assembly is:

```
.section .data
input_prompt:
.asciz "Enter a string of 0s and 1s: "
invalid_message:
.asciz "Invalid input: program terminating\n"
newline:
.byte 10
state:
.int 0  # initial state (EE)

.section .bss
input:
.byte 0

.section .text
.globl main

main:
# Print the input prompt
movl $4, %eax        # syscall: write
movl $1, %ebx        # file descriptor: stdout
lea input_prompt, %ecx  # pointer to the message
movl $29, %edx       # message length
int $0x80            # invoke syscall

# Read user input
movl $3, %eax        # syscall: read
movl $0, %ebx        # file descriptor: stdin
lea input, %ecx      # buffer to store input
movl $4, %edx        # buffer size
int $0x80            # invoke syscall
```

This essentially just reads a user input and that's it. What I need is to use call getchar@PLT to turn 1010 to "1" then "0" then "1" then "0". But how?

Comment: You should be using `getchar` not a read system call. Instead of your read block just do `call getchar@PLT` and that will return the char in `eax`. You will need to code the loop of course. Note you can ask gcc to generate assembly for you.

Comment: Compiler output from that C source will use `call getchar`.  (Use `-O1 -fPIE` to make it use `call getchar@PLT`).  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for more about using https://godbolt.org/ to have compilers make useful and readable examples.